# PrototypeJS version 1.6.0.2 Overrides JSON.parse and JSON.stringify and breaks socket.io functionality

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io, prototypejs

Basically, socket.io uses nativeJSON to enconde and decode packets, and my problem is that I am obliged to use this version of prototype which changes JSON behaviour. When I should get in the server something like:

`socket.on('event', function (a, b, c)`, 
I get 
`socket.on('event', function ([a, b, c], undefined, undefined)`.

One solution is to comment this lines on json.js:

```
/* socket.io-client/lib/json.js
if (nativeJSON && nativeJSON.parse){
    return exports.JSON = {
      parse: nativeJSON.parse
    , stringify: nativeJSON.stringify
    };
  }
*/
```

but this change affects performance seriously.

Is there a way to recover native JSON functionality?
Would it be possible to create a hidden iframe just to clone the JSON object to restore the old functionality?

Comment: I don't exactly understand the problem. Can you explain it a bit deeply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to kill Prototype's toJSON() extension methods:

```
if(window.Prototype) {
    delete Object.prototype.toJSON;
    delete Array.prototype.toJSON;
    delete Hash.prototype.toJSON;
    delete String.prototype.toJSON;
}
```

Then you should be able to use the browser's native JSON.parse/stringify methods without issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to kill everything, and have a code that would be okay on most browsers, you could do it this way :

```
(function (undefined) { // This is just to limit _json_stringify to this scope and to redefine undefined in case it was
  if (true ||typeof (Prototype) !== 'undefined') {
    // First, ensure we can access the prototype of an object.
    // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662147/how-to-access-object-prototype-in-javascript
    if(typeof (Object.getPrototypeOf) === 'undefined') {
      if(({}).__proto__ === Object.prototype && ([]).__proto__ === Array.prototype) {
        Object.getPrototypeOf = function getPrototypeOf (object) {
          return object.__proto__;
        };
      } else {
        Object.getPrototypeOf = function getPrototypeOf (object) {
          // May break if the constructor has been changed or removed
          return object.constructor ? object.constructor.prototype : undefined;
        }
      }
    }

    var _json_stringify = JSON.stringify; // We save the actual JSON.stringify
    JSON.stringify = function stringify (obj) {
      var obj_prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj),
          old_json = obj_prototype.toJSON, // We save the toJSON of the object
          res = null;
      if (old_json) { // If toJSON exists on the object
        obj_prototype.toJSON = undefined;
      }
      res = _json_stringify.apply(this, arguments);
      if (old_json)
        obj_prototype.toJSON = old_json;
      return res;
    };
  }
}.call(this));
```

This seems complex, but this is complex only to handle most use cases.
The main idea is overriding `JSON.stringify` to remove `toJSON` from the object passed as an argument, then call the old `JSON.stringify`, and finally restore it.