# Why does string concat apply not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I call `concat()` on a string as shown below:

```
> "1".concat("2","3")
< "123"
```

Now I want to do this for the case where I have an array of strings to concat togther.  But it doesn't do what I expect:

```
> "1".concat.apply(["2","3"])
< "2,3"
```

Not only is the first element missing, but a comma has been inserted between the two elements passed, like it was converting the argument in apply to a string and then returning that instead.

How can I use apply?  I can't use `String.prototype.concat.apply` because the first argument is actually a variable which could be string or array.  I would rather not do some awful hack where I have to detect the type and then have a separate statement for each possible type the argument could be.

To be clear, I am trying to implement a function `concat()` which works for any first argument type which makes sense (e.g. string or array).  So far it looks like this, but is not working:

```
function concat(x) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)
    return x.concat.apply(args)
}
```

Comment: It gives you a new array const `newArray = "1".concat("2","3")`

Comment: @michael just wondering if this happens in a particular browser or whether you've tested more than one

Comment: `["1", "2", "3"].join("")`?

Comment: @S.Imp I get the same result in both Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument of [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is the context, which needs to be the string. You'd use

```
const arr = ["2","3"];
console.log("1".concat(...arr));
console.log(String.prototype.concat.apply("1", arr));
console.log("".concat.apply("1", arr));
```

In your particular case, I'd recommend to use [rest/spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
function concat(x, ...args) {
    return x.concat(...args);
}
```

or in ES5

```
function concat(x) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return x.concat.apply(x, args);
//                        ^
}
```

Comment: excellent answer.  i'm so used to putting "null" or "this" as the first argument to apply, and it confused me when that started throwing errors so I removed it and found it didn't seem to mind (aside from returning the wrong result!)  Now it is obvious to me that what is happening is the first argument is being convert to a string and concatenated with nothing.

Comment: minification tools like uglify will barf on the ellipsis `...arr`. This may or may not be a consideration.

Comment: The spread approach presumably has implications for large arrays?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No other implications than `apply` has.

Comment: @S.Imp You should use a modern ES6-compatible minification tool then. I guess a more important consideration would be whether you need to support pre-ES6 browsers :-)

Comment: @bergi feel free to suggest one.

Comment: @S.Imp I cannot recommend any since I personally never used one, but [Google suggests a few](https://www.google.com?q=es6+minifier)

Answer (score 1):

When using a native function in JavaScript I recommend reading the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) first.

By calling `"1".concat` you get the raw function of the string object, thus losing the *context*. If you want to call a function using `apply`, the first parameter is an object the function uses as its `this` object or *context*.

So `"1".concat.apply(["2", "3"])` is semantically equivalent to `(""+["2", "3"]).concat()`.

I guess what you want to do is the following:

```
var unboundConcat = String.prototype.concat;
return unboundConcat.apply("1", ["2", "3"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the prototype `String.prototype` and join the array values  using the function `.join()`.

```js
console.log(String.prototype.concat("1", ["2","3"].join('')))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the concat according to the String or Array prototype, you can use [Object.getPrototypeOf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662147/how-to-access-object-prototype-in-javascript)

```js
var stringOrArray = "1"

   
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(stringOrArray).concat.apply(stringOrArray, ["2","3"]))

stringOrArray = ["1", "5"]

   
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(stringOrArray).concat.apply(stringOrArray, ["2","3"]))
```

Comment: @zfrisch that would give incorrect result when stringOrArray is an array

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `apply` is the context, or `this`.

in ES6:

- aORs   = array or String
- concatWith = what you are concatenating the array or string with

  `let concat = (aORs) => (concatWith) => aORs.concat(concatWith);`

```js
let concat = (aORs) => (concatWith) => aORs.concat(concatWith);

console.log(
  concat(["a", "b"])(1)
); 
//["a", "b", 1]

console.log(
  concat("1")(" 2")
);
// "1 2"
```

ES5

```
function concat(aORs) {
 return function(concatWith) {
   return aORs.concat(concatWith);
 }
}
```

```js
function concat(aORs) {
  return function(concatWith) {
    return aORs.concat(concatWith);
  }
}

console.log(
  concat("1")("abc")
);

console.log(
  concat([1, 2, 3])("abc")
);
```