# Not accesible propotype in javascript object

Tags: javascript

If I create a simple object like

```
var a = {foo: 1};
```

Why I can access to its prototype this way ?

```
a.prototype
```

I get undefined on the console

Comment: And you did not google it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662147/how-to-access-object-prototype-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_\_proto\_\_ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Functions** have a `prototype` property not regular objects. The `prototype` property points to an object that child objects created with `new` will be linked to.

Objects *are* prototype linked however. However this is not the same thing as the 
`prototype` property of functions This naming is a bit of confusing.

For example:

```js
var a = {foo: 1}; 

// the prototype of a
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(a))
// the same as __proto__
console.log(a.__proto__ === Object.getPrototypeOf(a))

// the .protoype property:
function Test(){}
// it's just an empty object unless you change it
console.log(Test.prototype)

// instance are prototype linked to this
let instance = new Test()
console.log(instance.__proto__ === Test.prototype)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the object's prototype this way:

```
a.__proto__
```

`obj.prototype` can be used to set new prototype to the object.